# How to return data via json

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, jax-rs

I'm trying to return information about `guests` (only an `id` and `name` right now) but I can't figure out how to properly do it.  My method is below

How can I sent only the id and name to `myData.put()` since java doesn't accept associative arrays?  I've tried creating a class within this method to be returned but that turns out to be illegal in java as well.  What's the idea solution here?

```
/**
 * Retrieves representation of an instance of contentmanagement.ContentManagement
 * @return an instance of java.lang.String
 */
@GET @Path("getHtml")
@Produces("application/json")
public String getGuests() {
    JSONArray myData = new JSONArray();

    for(Guest item : guestDao.getAllGuests()) {
        myData.put({});
    }

    return myData.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `JSONObject` class represents the name-value pair, so your code looks like:

```
/**
 * Retrieves representation of an instance of contentmanagement.ContentManagement
 * @return an instance of java.lang.String
 */
@GET @Path("getHtml")
@Produces("application/json")
public String getGuests() {
    JSONArray myData = new JSONArray();

    for(Guest item : guestDao.getAllGuests()) {
        myData.put(new JSONObject().put("id", item.getID())
          .put("name", item.getName()));
    } 

    return myData.toString();
}
```

Comment: Note that `JSONObject.put`[] returns `this`, allowing you to call the method multiple times in a chain. (See http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html)

Comment: I did that... now I get a `NullPointerException` :-\

Comment: Could you specify which object?

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException`